# Looking for Global Landcover Data

Tags: data

I am looking for a site to download detailed Global Landcover data.
I tried to download from GLCF site but not successful

Comment: What error did you face? Why were you not successful? We need more information before we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the product MCD12Q1 of MODIS. 
Here is http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD12Q1.051/2013.01.01/ and you can find more information about the product http://landval.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/MCD12Q1_c5.1_doc.pdf